# Cloud Run application throws Exception but doesn't log details

Tags: exception, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run application that crashes with a mysterious exception. For reasons (Mac Silicon...) I can't test locally, only deploy new versions on Cloud Run.

When I POST the offending request, I get back an internal error and I see a log `TIMESTAMP Exception in thread "main"`. Unfortunately, the rest of the stack trace does not get printed in the log line, either in the service or in the log explorer. Is there a way to get it to print the entire stack trace?

I am going to pepper my service with log lines but I was hoping to also figure out how to see the exception too.

Comment: Is your application written in Java? What is it interfacing with where dates are being processed?

Comment: You can run your container on Cloud Shell and see what's happen there. Let us know your code content and your cloud shell trace

Comment: This issue would be better handled through a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) as more information is needed for the investigation.

Comment: @JohnHanley I was being unclear with the TIMESTAMP thing, it's just the format I see the log line is. That is to say the timestamp is the timestamp the error in main happened. This app is in Scala so it's on the JVM.

Comment: @JMA I unfortunately didn't pay for support

Comment: Guillaume has a good idea for running your app on Cloud Shell for debugging.